# How to extract table data from an image using Vision Framework in iOS?

Tags: ios, opencv, computer-vision, coreml, visionkit

With iOS **Vision Framework**, I am able to perform OCR and fetch recognized text from an image using

> VNRecognizedTextObservation

Now let say, I have an image in which there is some text paragraph along with a table. The table has many columns and associated rows with it(Refer below image). Is it possible to recognize a particular column's key and values from the table using Vision?

For example, I want to fetch **2014 Retail Sales numbers** alone from the below image using Vision. How to do this? Can we use both **Vision** and **CoreML** to do this?

[image]

Comment: @moxmlb No. I ended up using Azure OCR services instead.

Comment: Yes Azure Form Recognizer does.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible using the vision

```
 guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else { return }
    let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage, orientation: .right)
    
    let size = CGSize(width: cgImage.width, height: cgImage.height) // note, in pixels from `cgImage`; this assumes you have already rotate, too
    let bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
    // Create a new request to recognize text.
    let request = VNRecognizeTextRequest { [self] request, error in
        guard
            let results = request.results as? [VNRecognizedTextObservation],
            error == nil
        else { return }
        
        let rects = results.map {
            convert(boundingBox: $0.boundingBox, to: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        }

    func convert(boundingBox: CGRect, to bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    let imageWidth = bounds.width
    let imageHeight = bounds.height
    
    // Begin with input rect.
    var rect = boundingBox
    
    // Reposition origin.
    rect.origin.x *= imageWidth
    rect.origin.x += bounds.minX
    rect.origin.y = (1 - rect.maxY) * imageHeight + bounds.minY
    
    // Rescale normalized coordinates.
    rect.size.width *= imageWidth
    rect.size.height *= imageHeight
    
    return rect
}
```

you can detect the **column's key** bounding box and extend the bounding box height

```
 var targetBoundingBox: CGRect?
        var targetWord = "Retailer"
        
        for result in results {
            if let candidate = result.topCandidates(1).first, candidate.string.lowercased().contains(targetWord.lowercased()) {
                targetBoundingBox = convert(boundingBox: result.boundingBox, to: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))

                targetBoundingBox?.size.height += bounds.maxY
                break
            }
        }

        if let targetBoundingBox = targetBoundingBox {
            print("Bounding box of '\(targetWord)': \(targetBoundingBox)")
            var textInsideTargetBox = ""
            for result in results {
                let boundingBox = convert(boundingBox: result.boundingBox, to: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
                if targetBoundingBox.intersects(boundingBox), let text = result.topCandidates(1).first?.string {
                    textInsideTargetBox += "\(text) "
                }
            }
            print(textInsideTargetBox,"string")
            let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
            format.scale = 1
            let final = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds, format: format).image { _ in
                image.draw(in: bounds)
                UIColor.green.setStroke()
                //                    for rect in rects {
                let path = UIBezierPath(rect: targetBoundingBox)
                path.lineWidth = 9
                path.stroke()
                //                    }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
                resultImage.image = final
            }

        } else {
            print("Bounding box of '\(targetWord)' not found")

        }
```